# How to "walk" through Word document making changes to the content?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I want to replace each character in file with another one.

Now I'm implementing it by using Find.Execute() method, but in this case it spends time for searching and then replaces it, then search for another character from the beginning of file again, so if I want to replace all the alphabetic letters it will go through the whole document 26 x2 (lower case and upper case) =48 times, but I want it to replace by 1 lookup, so like: It get the first character it is "a" replace with " a' ", if the next char is "c" replace with "s" etc, make it by one look up, so it goes through the whole document only one time.

I know I can implement it just by writing my own code, but I'm wondering may be there is some built-in class that can ease my life :)

Comment: Something here help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document_members%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: VBA is built in script language in of Word. But what do you mean by C#? Are you referring to an add-on or a stand-alone application?

Comment: try to revise your question. :)

Comment: I'm writing stand alone application for transliteration.

Comment: sorry, not VBA, I ment VB..

Comment: What I want is, to make all the replacement, but without searching.. I just need to read the document letter by letter and replace them... 

using the Selection seems to be working for me, but why all the examples given in VB...not C#

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

//...

Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
Word.Document myDoc = app.Documents.Add(pathToMyDoc);

for(int n = 0; n < myDoc.Characters.Count; ++n)
{
  myDoc.Characters[n].Text = LookupReplacement(myDoc.Characters[n].Text);
}
```

Completely untested but might help you. Link I looked at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documentclass(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this for reference , Hope this helps:

http://weblogs.asp.net/guystarbuck/archive/2008/05/13/automated-search-and-replace-in-multiple-word-2007-documents-with-c.aspx

Comment: That's actually what I did, but I don't like this solution... couse it searches my document again and again, so if I want to replace all 26 alphabet letter, it will loop my document 26 times, as I stated above.

What I want is, to make all the replacement, but without searching.. I just need to read the document letter by letter and replace them...